# How to switch between table or list html with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to give user option to choose how data to be displayed- table or list style. Is this possible by switching buttons? Is it better to be done with page reload or dinamically with DOM manipulation? I'm a rookie still with Javascript and jQuery and need a little push here. Thanks!

EDIT: 
For example I want all table tags to be switched with divs or ul.
This is a common Wordpress post loop.

Here is my code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Picture</th>
            <th>Category</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post();?>

        <tr>

            <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
            <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'my-taxonomy', '', ', ' )); ?></td>

        </tr>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: you could use jQuery `.html()`, but that could become kind of unwieldy with large blocks of code.

Comment: What is your source data? JSON? Or do you have static html that you want to manipulate?

Comment: Let's say I have a static html because when the user sees the results, the server already made it's calculations.

Comment: @Charles I didn't try anything so far. Still looking for a good start push. Which event to handle? Should I remove, just replace the html or just call another html if button is in state Table or List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution: 
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/list-grid-view

It works perfectly for me, as I use Bootstrap framework.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the button to add a layout classname to a parent element and use CSS to override the default styles.

So, perhaps your default layout is list:

```
.mystuff {
    /* list-styles */ 
}
```

... and later, for the table-layout:

```
.mystuff.table {
    /* override CSS for table-layout */
}
```